# linux-generate not installable

Tags: apt, kernel

I have a Dockerfile that compiles a custom linux kernel based on Ubuntu 22.04. It has been working fine until this morning, but now fails at the step where it runs `apt-get update && apt-get build-dep -y linux linux-signed` giving this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:linux-signed : Depends: linux-generate (= 5.15.0-60.66) but it is not installable
```

I have all `deb-src` lines uncommented in my apt sources.

```
root@ef3c9ab828f8:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep deb-src
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
```

What is `linux-generate`? No matter where I look (google, `apt-cache search`, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-generate) I can't find that package or any information about it.

---

Update

Here is a minimal Dockerfile to produce the issue (tested on two different hosts):

```dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN sed -i 's/# deb-src/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get build-dep -y linux linux-signed
```

Update 2:

```
root@16e6b6976fda:/# apt policy linux-generate
N: Unable to locate package linux-generate
```

Comment: Thanks, guiverc. Indeed I meant Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy linux-generate` to your question.

Comment: Added, @OrganicMarble.

Comment: So the version of linux-signed you are working with is referencing a package that is not on your system. Weird.

Comment: @OrganicMarble for build dependencies you mean.  I don't believe that package as a build dependency is made available in Ubuntu's repos directly, nor do I think that a Docker image is where you should be trying to compile a kernel for the reasons of it not being a full system container image, and not running the "kernel" of Ubuntu or Linux, but rather relying on host system kernel mappings/bindings via Docker to whatever the host system is (Windows kernel for instance if on a Windows host)

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that this is an issue in Canonical's apt repo, given the missing package and the fact that it worked while `5.15.0-58` was the last version of the 5.15.0 kernel in the repo.

Comment: Any update on that? In november 2022 I was able to compile the kernel from a docker and now I'm getting that same message (builddeps:linux-signed : Depends: linux-generate (= 5.4.0-139.156) but it is not installable). I'm using Kernel 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: Only partial solution.*

I'm using a slightly different build approach on ubuntu 20.04. Using the current kernel version 5.4.0-144 (as of 2023-03-03). My build script runs following commands:

```
sed -i 's/# deb-src/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
apt -y build-dep linux-image-5.4.0-144-generic
```

This fails with `builddeps:linux-signed : Depends: linux-generate (= 5.4.0-144.161) but it is not installable`

However, if no kernel version is specified, the command will succeed:

```
sed -i 's/# deb-src/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
apt -y build-dep linux-image-generic
```

This work around also works for ubuntu 22.04.